# How to write a "shortest path" like command or at least a "find a path" command in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imaging, there are social-media-data in a table like this:

```
u1 u2
0  3
1  2
1  4
2  3
3  1
3  4
```

It means:

- User 0 follows User 3
- User 1 follows User 2
- User 1 follows User 4
- ...

Now I want to know: Is there a way/path from User 0 to User 2?

Yes. User 0 follows User 3. User 3 follows User 1. User 1 follows User 2.

**But how can a solve this problem as a SQL-Command?**

I want to know if there is such a path. Optional I want to know what the path is. And is it possible to get the shortest path somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get tree path in MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141105/get-tree-path-in-mysql-table)

Comment: MySQL does not really support hierarchical or recursive queries.  You can do this with a stored procedure, using recursion or a while loop.

Comment: What version of MySQL? It's possible to do it in MySQL 8.x, but not in MySQL 5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below works in MySQL 8.x since it requires a "Recursive Common Table Expression" (Recursive CTE):

```
with n (initial, path, current) as (
  select u1, concat('', u1, '/', u2), u2  from my_table 
    where u1 = 0 -- initial node
  union all 
  select n.initial, concat(n.path, '/', m.u2), m.u2
    from my_table m
    join n on n.current = m.u1
)
select * from n 
  where current = 2 -- target node
```

However, if you are using MySQL 5.x, then you're out of luck (to the best of my knowledge).